# How to write if else in one line in shell?

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement

I would like to write in one line this:

```
if [$SERVICESTATEID$ -eq 2]; then echo "CRITICAL"; else echo "OK"; fi
```

So to do a test in my shell I did:

```
if [2 -eq 3]; then echo "CRITICAL"; else echo "OK"; fi
```

The result is

```
-bash: [2: command not found
OK
```

So it doesn't work.

Comment: Keep in mind, that `[` is the name of a program. And after the name of a program must be a space. It is the same as in `ls *.txt`. This `ls*.txt` would fail, too.

Comment: Ok thx it's works now !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Space -- the final frontier. This works:

```
if [ $SERVICESTATEID -eq 2 ]; then echo "CRITICAL"; else echo "OK"; fi
```

Note spaces after `[` and before `]` -- `[` is a command name! And I removed an extra `$` at the end of `$SERVICESTATEID`.

An alternative is to spell out `test`. Then you don't need the final `]`, which is what I prefer:

```
if test $SERVICESTATEID -eq 2; then echo "CRITICAL"; else echo "OK"; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Write like this, space is required before and after `[` and `]` in shell

```
if [ 2 -eq 3 ]; then echo "CRITICAL"; else echo "OK"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter format.

```sh
( [ 2 -eq 3 ] && echo "CRITICAL" ) || echo "OK"
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex pattern type numbers : 10,12.1,+3.33,-1,0004,-48.9
Oneliner attacks again!

```
( [ `echo $number 2>/dev/null | grep -E "^[ ]*(\+|\-){0,1}[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$"` ] && echo "NUMBER" ) || echo "NOT NUMBER"
```

Comment: I really don't see how the code relates to the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)